# Concatenate Regex with string in C#

Tags: c#

I am new in using Regex and have one scenerio of automation in Winappdriver using C# , where my full file path is continuously changing.

some e.gs are : tmp76A5\Original Letter 2017.docx , tmpA7D\Original Letter 2017.docx, tmpZ90S\Original Letter 2017.docx

so, basically I am capturing file name in file variable as below :

var file = Original Letter 2017.docx

But how can i capture the full file path i.e "tmp76A5\Original Letter 2017.docx" where values in first word is continuously changing after tmp

I tried using :
var regex = new Regex(@"(tmp.*)+\file");

But no luck.

My code is written as below :

```
public void ValidatePath(ExtentTest childNode, string value, string filePath)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            var file = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
           var regex = new Regex(@"tmp[0-9A-Z]*\\file");
            _fileSelectionForm.ValidateOriginalDocumentPath(childNode, filePath);
            _fileSelectionForm.ValidateModifiedDocumentPath(childNode, regex.ToString());
        }
```

Where: filePath : D:\user\Original Letter 2017.docx

```
   Here the path with which i will be comparing in ValidateModifiedDocumentPath is "C:\Users\komal.verma982\AppData\Local\Temp\Workshare\tmp1347\Original Letter 2017.docx"
```

where value of tmp after Workshare is continously changing to tmp1347,tmpA65D, tmpA0B6

Cany anybody help me out in this. ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: If you want to parse a file path why not use the [`Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path?view=netcore-3.1) class `Path.GetFileName` and `Path.GetDirectoryName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this seems to work:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"tmp[0-9A-Z]*\\Original Letter 2017.docx";
        string input = @"tmp76A5\Original Letter 2017.docx ,
tmpA7D\Original Letter 2017.docx, 
tmpZ90S\Original Letter 2017.docx";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

However, this is not the usual approach to handle filenames. You should maybe split the filename first, but that will depend on your needs.

If you have to get the name of folder where the file is, you can just do:

```
var strPath = @"D:\user\Original Letter 2017.docx";
var dirname = Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(strPath));
Console.WriteLine(dirname); // "user"
```

Comment: Hi @Pablo, Thanks for the response. I have edited the question . Can you check if you can help as current provided solution is not working.

Comment: @user12675659 I think you don't need a regex to get the path, check my last update for getting the dir name.

Comment: Hi @Pablo,  I tried one more approach where i have written :  var File = Path.GetFileName(filePath);    string pattern = $@"tmp[0-9A-Z]*\{File}"; where filePath: D:\\CMP-6286\\Original Letter 2017.docx But i am getting an error : Unrecognized space sequence. So why pattern is not recognizing" \" character. Is there any other way to define this.  Thanks in advance

Comment: @user12675659 I suggest you to test your regex in an online tool like this one: https://regexr.com/ probably you need to encode that \ in another way.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Pablo